# attr() in my scss files?

Tags: compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a print style sheet and overriding certain styles when I noticed `a[href]:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")"}` which was putting the url after the link name. I am using compass and foundation so I figured that it should be a function in one of those.

I've looked through the [foundation source](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss) and the [function list in compass](http://compass-style.org/index/functions/) and I can't find any `attr` functions. Is this a css thing or am I just not looking in the correct files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr()` is a CSS expression that can be used to retrieve various attributes of the selected element. More info available on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

Comment: wow I was trying to find something like that for hours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the `_type.scss` file - https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_type.scss

You could override it with something like

```
a[href]:after { content: "" !important; }
```

Comment: I'm more trying to understand why `attr()` works and where the function is defined.